# How can I implement an "Object Buffer" which can limit memory size?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, architecture

Firstly, I know that most modern software has features like **"limit the memory usage"** of some particular part. This software may use `OS-level API` or `memory pool` or other advanced techniques I don't know to implement this kind of feature.
But so far I'm writing on a small program so I want to be as simple as possible, here's my problem:

Suppose I have a class with some complex STL data structures

```cpp
class ComplexStructure {
private:
    std::map<AAA, BBB> struct1;
    std::vector<CCC> struct2;
    std::unordered_map<DDD, EEE> struct3;
public:
    void generate_some_data();
    void delete_some_data();
};
```

`generate` method can insert some data into these structures, `delete` method can erase some data from these structures. Obviously, they can change memory usage.

Now I have a "buffer" class which specifically designed for storing `ComplexStructure` (may also partially act as a "factory"). It has a `max_size` to limit # of bytes of these `ComplexStructures`

```cpp
class ComplexStructureBuffer {
private:
    size_t max_size;
    size_t size;
    std::list<ComplexStructure> list;
public:
    bool is_full();
    ComplexStructure& create(params...);
    void erase(ComplexStructure&);
}
```

My question is:

1. How can I know the accurate memory usage of `ComplexStructure`? Of course, 100% accuracy is impossible, but at least we should be able to count the bytes that are allocated by the `new` operator, right?
2. How can I "link" `ComplexStructure` to this "buffer" in some way (NOTE there may have multiple buffers, so can't use a global parameter), so that when call `generate` or `delete` method, they can update `size` member variable and know if the buffer is full?

Currently the only solution I have is to declare `const size_t& max_size` and `size_t& size` in `ComplexStructure`. When generating or deleting data, use `sizeof` and # of items to estimate memory usage. This solution is very ugly and horribly inaccurate, it shouldn't be that way.

The additional solution may be somehow **"hook"** the allocator used in every STL container so that whenever they allocate memory, we can know the actual size. But I don't know how to implement it.

Seems like not only c++, all programming languages don't have this kind of feature. There should be something wrong, is this demand so rare, or my design is completely broken?

Comment: You can provide your own allocator for containers. [Boost.Pool](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.pool) provides some options. You say a few times you don't know how to do things. If you are interested in doing this then you have an opportunity to do some research and learn how.

Answer (score 0):

1. There are no accurate ways to measure memory use. You can get the exact size of a type using `sizeof` operator, but that won't account for things that may be allocated dynamically, such as the elements of the containers.
2. You shouldn't use the `size` member variable. The size is already stored in the container, and the container keeps it updated for you. You should just compare `list.size()`.

---

For a practical implementation of limiting memory, I recommend not to limit certain types, but memory use in general. There is no standard way to limit memory use in C++, but operating systems do provide such functionality. If you wish to limit  memory use of a part of a program, I would recommend starting a child process, running the part there, and limit the memory of the child process. There is no standard way in C++ to create child processes.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It turns out that measuring memory use of a certain type isn't practical, I'll try your advice instead. BTW the `size` member variable was meant to be # of total bytes, not # of items. But of course it won't be used anymore.